# I only get one value in Mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I am making a small browser game and I have a database where the high scores of the users are stored.
[here an image of the database (name is the username and M1_CPM the score)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smMm9.png)

with the following code I am trying to get the top 10 values to later desplay them on a leaderboard:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM leaderboard ORDER BY M1_CPM DESC LIMIT 10";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    exit();
}
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
echo implode(",", mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData));
```

The problem is that it always only echoes the highest score and not the top ten. Why?

Comment: Because `mysqli_fetch_assoc` only fetches one row at a time. You need to loop until there are no rows left. Almost any example / tutorial etc would show you this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mysql_fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) function returns only one row from a recordset as an associative array. to retrieve all rows use a while loop:

```php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData))
{
   echo implode(",", $row);
}
```

> Note: After the data is retrieved, this function moves to the next row in the recordset. Each subsequent call to mysql_fetch_assoc() returns the next row in the recordset.

Answer (score 1):

Each time when mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) is accessed, the pointer moves to the next record. At last when no records are found, it returns null which breaks the while condition. 
So you need first get the data with `while` and then use implode, sth like this

```
$rows = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

And then you can use `implode`, so your code will become like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM leaderboard ORDER BY M1_CPM DESC LIMIT 10";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    exit();
}
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

$rows = [];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo implode(",", $rows);
```